# More efficient way of iterating over a text-file in python?

Tags: python, list, text-files

What I have attempted to do is read the file and store the information in separate lists. For this program a small example file is used to first ensure the code works but this program will deal with photos in the 100,000's and this doesn't seem like the best way to index the file for optimal efficiency. This is what I have so far:

```
with open('a_example.txt') as example_file:    
    content = [i.strip() for i in example_file.readlines()]
    
    number_of_photos = content[0]
    del content[0] #remove the numphoto info
    for j in content:
        orientation_of_photo.append(j[0])
        number_of_tags.append(j[2])
```

Comment: What efficiency are you worrying about? CPU, RAM, DiskIO, ...? What's wrong with the code? Who complains and why? Ask that person what efficiency would be acceptable.

Comment: Stop using `.example_file.readlines()`, you can iterate directly over file objects, `content = [i.strip() for i in examplefile.readlines()]` although you are working with small files, this won't really affect things, since the bulk of the time will be spent on I/O

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can tell you are indexing the file is to get the first line.

You can use `next()` to get this, then continue on with the loop

```
with open('a_example.txt') as example_file:    
    number_of_photos = next(example_file).strip()
    for line in example_file:
        j = line.strip()
        orientation_of_photo.append(j[0])
        number_of_tags.append(j[2])
```

Comment: maybe, `orientation, _, num_tags = line.strip()`

Comment: Maybe, but I would think "number of tags" should be more than a single digit/character